# WatchOS Complication: is it possible to use custom text alignment?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

I've been developing a watchOS 2 complication for my app. It's looking great... asides from one last thing I'd like to tweak.

Complication templates seem to provide text alignment that isn't quite what I want. For the purpose of this question, let's go with the following code:

```
let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallStackText()
template.line1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Hi")
template.line2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Bye")
```

Now, looking at the complication, the first line is centre aligned, while the second line is left aligned. Not a massive deal I know, but I'd really like both lines to be centre aligned... it would make my complication look much better!

I've been looking through the API docs and searched the web, and I can't see a way to do this (or anyone else that's tried to do the same thing).

### Questions:

- Has anyone else run into the same issue?
- Is there something in the API that I've missed that lets you do this?
- If not, is there any slightly more hacky/obtuse way of achieving what I'd like?

Comment: @PetahChristian well, that was a little interesting. Looks like my text was appended by a space or two... doh. A much easier issue than it seemed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are limited by the predetermined layout that Apple has chosen for each particular template, and can't control the alignment.

[Filing a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) is your best option to address any issue or request an enhancement.

I can't reproduce your issue on watchOS 2.2 or 3.0 beta 1.  line 2 *is* centered for that particular template.

If you're supporting an earlier watchOS version which behaves differently, you could see if any [Unicode space characters](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) or [`textProviderWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/clockkit/clktextprovider/1627899-textproviderwithformat?language=objc) would help to improve the appearance.